# SQL query for 3 tables and more

Tags: sql, join

for the following schema:

```
Publisher (name, phone, city), PK: name.
Book (ISBN, title, year, published_by, previous_edition, price), PK: ISBN, FK: published_by refs Publisher, previous_edition refs Book.
Author (SSN, first_name, last_name, address, income), PK: SSN.
Write (aSSN, bISBN), PK: (aSSN, bISBN), FK: aSSN refs Author, bISBN refs Book.
Editor (SSN, first_name, last_name, address, salary, works_for, book_count), PK: SSN, FK: works_for refs Publisher.
Edit (eSSN, bISBN), PK: (eSSN, bISBN), FK: eSSN refs Editor, bISBN refs Book.
Author_Editor (aeSSN, hours), PK: aeSSN, FK: aeSSN refs Author, aeSSN refs Editor.
```

Is this the correct way to do it? If not, can I get a hint please (any hint is appreciated)?

```
Select author.first_name, author.last_name
From author 
JOIN edit
ON author.ssn=edit.essn
Join write
Where edit.bisbn=write.bisbn and edit.isbn is not null;
```

Provide the title, year, and publisher name of every book and the first name and last name of the editor of the book.

```
SELECT title, year, published_by, first_name, last_name
FROM Book, 
Join Edit on ISBN=eSNN
Join Editor on SSN=eSSN
```

Provide the title of those books whose author’s last name is neither “Smith” nor “Doe”.

```
SELECT title

FROM book inner join write 
On book.isbn=write.bisbn
Join author on write.aSNN=Author.SNN
WHERE Author.last_name=’Doe’ and Author.first_name=’Smith’
```

Comment: Judging from your wording, I'm guessing this is a homework assignment?

Answer (score 0):

You're close. When writing a join, you need to specify the table and column names, and do the same for every join. So it would be something like this for your second example:

> Provide the title, year, and publisher name of every book and the
>   first name and last name of the editor of the book.

```
SELECT book.title, 
       book.[year], 
       book.published_by, 
       editor.first_name, 
       editor.last_name 
FROM   book, 
       inner 
       JOIN edit 
         ON book.isbn = edit.bisbn 
       INNER JOIN editor 
               ON edit.essn = editor.ssn
```

Comment: Oh, yeah, this looks like a homework assignment. Are there rules about that? OP, try to correct the others on your own. Once you get a few done and see the pattern this type of problem should become pretty straightforward for you.

Comment: `[year]` is not a valid identifier in (standard) SQL. The question is not tagged with a specific DBMS, so the answer should use standard SQL as well.

Answer (score 0):

While there are some ORM's that handle guessing the PKs/FKs on which to join at higher levels, at this level you're going to typically need to explicitly specify on which columns you would like the data 'matched up' on

```
SELECT b.title, 
       b.year, 
       b.published_by, 
       ed.first_name, 
       ed.last_name 
FROM   book b, 
       inner 
       JOIN edit e 
         ON b.isbn = e.bisbn 
       JOIN editor ed
         ON e.essn = ed.ssn
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ahh I have no idea why I put that! Thanks for the heads up my good sir!

Comment: @venenum does this help? If so, would really appreciate it if you selected this as the answer!